# matplotlib pcolor faceted not working

Tags: python, matplotlib

I try to run the following script (with python 2.7):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
print matplotlib.__version__

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.figure()
plt.pcolor(np.random.random((10,10)),shading="faceted")
plt.show()
```

and get the output:

```
1.1.1rc2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 7, in <module>
    plt.pcolor(np.random.random((10,10)),shading="faceted")
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 2413, in pcolor
    ret = ax.pcolor(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/axes.py", line 7044, in pcolor
    if 'antialiaseds' not in kwargs and ec.lower() == "none":
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'lower'
```

When I look in /usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/axes.py, I see:

```
        if shading == 'faceted':
        edgecolors = 'k',
    else:
        edgecolors = 'none'
    if 'edgecolor' in kwargs:
        kwargs['edgecolors'] = kwargs.pop('edgecolor')
    ec = kwargs.setdefault('edgecolors', edgecolors)

    # aa setting will default via collections to patch.antialiased
    # unless the boundary is not stroked, in which case the
    # default will be False; with unstroked boundaries, aa
    # makes artifacts that are often disturbing.
    if 'antialiased' in kwargs:
        kwargs['antialiaseds'] = kwargs.pop('antialiased')
    if 'antialiaseds' not in kwargs and ec.lower() == "none":
            kwargs['antialiaseds'] = False
```

The Problem seems to be the "," after edgecolors = 'k'. Because like this, edgecolors is not a string but a tuple....

I did not have this problems with older versions of matplolib

Answer (score 0):

Using `Matplotlib 1.2.1` your routine works for me. `Axes.py` in `matplotlib 1.2.1` contains following lines instead of that in your version of `axes.py`.

```
    if 'antialiaseds' not in kwargs and (is_string_like(ec) and
            ec.lower() == "none"):
```

I guess you should update your matplotlib installation.